# wordpress wp-admin showing white screen with no error

Tags: wordpress

I know I have posted same questions but all same question will not solve my issue.

Suddenly my wordpress site wp-admin stop working. When I will try to access wp-admin it will display white screen. I have deactivated all plugin by rename plugin folder , also uploaded fresh wp-admin and wp-include folder but same problem.

I have also replace wp-config file with fresh file but no luck.

When I will try to access with wp-login.php it will work but showing:

```
ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output
```

Even my browser cookie is already enabled.

It will be greatful if any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: did you try to rename current theme ?

Comment: Even better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: check : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-log-in-cookies-are-blocked-due-to-unexpected-output?replies=37

Comment: I have tried all solution but still no luck

Comment: You did? So, what are the error messages you found in your error log?

Comment: I have check and error log file doesn't exists in root folder

Comment: I resolved by doing this. http://naveedramzan.com/how-to-fix-empty-dashboard-issue-in-wordpress/
although its not good solution to change in core file.

Comment: screen.php having 224 line only... not found any code which is mentioned in your blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time when you're seeing a white screen in wordpress, it's something you added to your functions.php file or a custom plugin that acts as an alternative to the functions.php file.  If you've made any adjustments to these, go back and remove those adjustments and it should return to normal.  There's most likely an error in something you added.